# Error in execute stored procedure including LIMIT statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, import, phpmyadmin, limit

I have a problem with executing my .sql file which includes some stored procedures. Errors are with all procedures that have `LIMIT` statement in their `SELECT`! and when I remove that part, it's OK. actually I don't have any problem in local with them!

Even when try to type some procedure in phpMyAdmin on the server with the same statement there is no problem but with copy & paste it exists again!

I checked my collation and unicode, but there was no unmatched case.

Any idea?

This is my code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_Select_Admin_Products`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SP_Select_Admin_Products`(IN p_start INT UNSIGNED, IN p_limit TINYINT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE `status` = 1 LIMIT p_start, p_limit;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

And this is my error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p_start, p_limit;
```

Comment: Please add the procedure and the whole error message.

Comment: is your MySQL at least version 5.5.6?

Comment: The docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html): say that "Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6."